# How to get response from AJAX to facebook dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I need to get response['cloudUrl'] from my AJAX to my fb share dialog, all happening at the same time as user clicks on #sharebutton.

I can't put my code in AJAX success, if I wrap it in something else other than user click event, browser will most likely to block my fb share popup.

To make things clearer, I can get response['cloudUrl'] in the AJAX success callback.

```
function submitDataToFbShare(){
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : 'www.testing.com/fb-data")',
        type : 'POST',
        data : 
        {
            name: $('.nameField').val(),
            personality_index: $('.nameField').val(),
            country: $( "#countryList select:first-child option:selected").attr("value"),
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(response) 
        {   
            console.log("Successfully saved!");
            console.log("response " + response['cloudUrl']);
        },
        error : function(request,error)
        {
            console.log("Error saving data!");
        }
    });
}


$('#sharebutton').click(function(e){
    submitDataToFbShare();

    e.preventDefault();
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
         link: "www.test.com",
         name: "test",
         description: "testing description",
         picture: response['cloudUrl'],
       }, function(response)
       {
            if (response != null || response != undefined)
            {
                console.log("success");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("failed");
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can’t have it both ways, either you want to call the method directly, or you want to make an AJAX request first. You could try whether a synchronous AJAX request that calls `FB.ui` afterwards does not make it get caught in the popup blocker; if that doesn’t work, then you will have to find a different method of getting the URL you need before the dialog is triggered.

Comment: @CBroe but isn't a synchronous AJAX a bad thing to do? And what do you mean by calling the method directly?

Comment: Yes, it is rather bad. But if you want to request information necessary for the dialog only when the user has clicked somewhere already, it might be your only choice, if you want to avoid the popup blocker. (And calling it directly means from the click handler, which will make most popup blockers let it go through, because it is directly connected to a user interaction, whereas if you call it from within a callback function to an asynchronous call, it is not any more.)

Comment: @CBroe I just tested using `async: false`, still the response I'm trying to get in the `FB.ui` is not defined

Comment: Of course you will need to change your code a bit more than just adding `async: false` to the AJAX request … the whole way you deal with the response changes in that case.